# Lists vs Matrices: Which one is faster?

Tags: list, matrix, time-complexity

Let X and Y be a matrix and a list respectively, both with the exact same size, elements and pattern. Assuming we need to retrieve the (nth) element from both, which method is faster? If i'm not mistaken, in languages like C or C++, the first case is computed as (matrix_pointer+step)* which should give O(θ) time (a.k.a. constant) since its just an addition, while in languages like Prolog or Haskell, while working with lists, you need to pass through the (nth-1) element to get to the (nth) one, which must give O(n) complexity.

Any clarification would be much appreciated.

Comment: Alright, so O(1) is the 'cost' for accessing array indices while using a certain language. My question is, what would the 'cost' be to fetch the same element, if that language supported lists too and we chose to solve that problem with lists instead of matrices? *Note: Assuming every other variable is kept constant. In simple words, in average case, which is most efficient? Matrix or List usage?

Comment: Yeah but as our data get larger, the first method (with matrices) will always need the same time no matter what cell we need to access, but if we choose to do this with lists, it will scale relative to n (our input), right? I assumed time complexity is the 'cost'.

Comment: When you say "list", I'm assuming a dynamic array. Are you talking about a linked list? If so, then yeah, it's apples and oranges from a complexity standpoint and getting the nth element is O(1) with an array or dynamic list/`ArrayList` (or matrix, same thing) and O(n) for a linked list.

Comment: Yeah, i suppose. I dont know how Prolog handles lists internally. I had the suspision arrays are faster cause even if you wanna get the last element (for example), it only needs an addition, while Prolog will force you to run through all previous elements before you get there, so the 'cost' is much bigger than a plain addition. I dont know if i made myself clear yet.

Comment: No, seems clear to me. I don't know Prolog or Haskell, so I shouldn't have assumed you were talking about dynamic lists.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. May i ask you one more question about what's the difference between linked lists and dynamic lists? (ArrayList as you mentioned). I was taught a list is basically a <value/s>+<pointer> to the next value (which i assume is what you refered to as 'linked lists'). Im not aware of the second term (Dynamic Lists)

Comment: Dynamic lists (JS's arrays, C#'s `List`, Python's lists, Java's `ArrayList`, C++'s `vector`) are more common than linked lists in most languages other than C and are basically expandable arrays that have extra properties and methods statically allocated arrays don't have (`push`, `pop`, `splice`, `slice`, `reverse` etc). Indexing into them might require object access but is still O(1).

Comment: So basically matrices, while (i guess) the cost to 'extend' them is constant. Thats awesome! Thanks for the insight :)